# Customized Titlebar android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, titlebar

i found very pretty title bar, my question is, does anybody of you guys know how to make this?

i tried to google something like this many times, but i didnt figured out how to hide the first half of titlebar and make the other half transparent. Thanks for your answers

this is screenshot from application called AIDE where i found this titlebar.

[image: titlebar]

Comment: I'd contain my current layout in a `RelativeLayout`, then add alongside it the title bar, by placing it in the upper right corner.

Comment: you can use table layout for that type of design

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this with ActionBar.

Checkout ActionBarSherlock at [actionbarsherlock.com](http://actionbarsherlock.com)

And its demo at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos&hl=en

Good luck!